# Calculating overlap in Mx2 and Nx2 matrices

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices A and B, both contain a list of event start and stop times:

```
A(i,1) = onset time of event i
A(i,2) = offset time of event i
B(j,1) = onset of event j
...
```

My goal is to get two lists of indecies `aIdx` and `bIdx` such that `A(aIdx,:)` and `B(bIdx,:)` contain the sets of events that are overlapping.

I've been scratching my head all day trying to figure this one out. Is there a quick, easy, matlaby way to do this?

I can do it using for loops but this seems kind of hacky for matlab:

```
aIdx = [];
bIdx = []
for i=1:size(A,1)
    for j=i:size(B,1)
        if overlap(A(i,:), B(j,:)) % overlap is defined elsewhere
            aIdx(end+1) = i;
            bIdx(end+1) = j;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Finding `aIdx` and `bIdx` are independent problems, right?

Comment: not at all aIdx and bIdx are tightly related, `aIdx(i)` and `bIdx(i)`  refer to the index in A and the index in B where the `i`th overlap in time occurs

Comment: Do the events always happens consecutively, i.e. if an even i occurs, will a event j get triggered after it, and before the next i event?

Comment: the events in both lists are sorted by the onset time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a zero loop solution:

```
overlap = @(x, y)y(:, 1) < x(:, 2) & y(:, 2) > x(:, 1)
[tmp1, tmp2] = meshgrid(1:size(A, 1), 1:size(B, 1));
M = reshape(overlap(A(tmp1, :), B(tmp2, :)), size(B, 1), [])';
[aIdx, bIdx] = find(M);
```

Comment: This gives incorrect results in several test cases. Notably, for `A = [1.0 2.0; 3.0 10.0; 2.8 4.4]; B = [3.0 10.0; 3.1 5.0; 3.1 4.5; 1.1 1.9];` I'm tinkering to see why, but it appears that syntax like `B(tmp2,:)` yields a sort of `repmat()` version of `B`. It's almost like you're extending A and B to reach the LCM of their column lengths, and then doing the checking, which is not correct. That would be consistent with using `meshgrid` for the coordinates too.

Comment: Did you check my edited overlap function? No, I'm not extending anything. I'm just making all combinations of rows between `A` and `B`.

Comment: That appears to have fixed it. It won't let me un-down-vote yet, but I will later.

Comment: It says now that I cannot upvote unless the question is edited. Can you make some trivial edit and I will upvote?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. At least on the quick test set I was using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one loop:

```
aIdx = false(size(A,1),1);
bIdx = false(size(B,1),1);
for k = 1:size(B,1)
    ai = ( A(:,1) >= B(k,1) & A(:,1) <= B(k,2) ) | ...
           ( A(:,2) >= B(k,1) & A(:,2) <= B(k,2) );
    if any(ai), bIdx(k) = true; end
    aIdx = aIdx | ai;
end
```

There is a way to create a vectorized algorithm. (I wrote a similar function before, but cannot find it right now.) A simply workflow is to (1) combine both matrices, (2) create an index to indicate source of each event, (3) create a matrix indicating start and stop positions, (4) vectorized and sort, (5) find overlaps with diff, cumsum, or combination.

Answer (score 1):

```
overlap_matrix = zeros(size(A,1),size(B,1))

for jj = 1:size(B,1)
    overlap_matrix(:,jj) = (A(:,1) <= B(jj,1)).*(B(jj,1) <= A(:,2));       
end

[r,c] = find(overlap_matrix)
% Now A(r(i),:) overlaps with B(c(i),:)

% Modify the above conditional if you want to also check
% whether events in A start in-between the events in B
% as I am only checking the first half of the conditional
% for simplicity.
```

Comment: Thats basically what I have done except I skip the `overlap_matrix` step

Comment: If you want to compare each element of the first column of A with each element of the first column of B, there's no way to do it except a loop. It might be possible to execute it with a function call to something like `filter` or `accumarray`, but it would be silly to do it that way; it would still be the same loop and would merely obfuscate the code. Since you're talking about an ordering (using < or > operators) and not merely set equality, the set methods like `intersect` and `setdiff` won't help either. I think the for-loop is the best solution.

Comment: I edited a way that might work to vectorize one of the loops at least. I stick by my claim that you can't get away with zero loops here, and would be really interested if you discover a way. But do check my edited version, because it works in my test cases but I don't know if I am correctly testing all the use cases you want.

Answer (score 0):

Completely vectorized code without repmat or reshape (hopefully faster too). I have assumed that the function "overlap" can give a vector of 1's and 0's if complete pairs of A(req_indices,:) and B(req_indices,:) are fed to it. If overlap can return a vector output, then the vectorization can be performed as given below.

Let rows in A matrix be Ra and Rows in B matrix be Rb,

```
AA=1:Ra;
AAA=AA(ones(Rb,1),:);
AAAA=AAA(:); % all indices of A arranged in desired format, i.e. [11...1,22..2,33...3, ...., RaRa...Ra]'

BB=(1:Rb)';
BBB=BB(:,ones(Ra,1)); 
BBBB=BBB(:);% all indices of B arranged in desired format, i.e. [123...Rb, 123...Rb,....,123...Rb]'

% Use overlap function
Result_vector = overlap(A(AAAA,:), B(BBBB,:));
Result_vector_without_zeros = find(Result_vector);
aIdx = AAAA(Results_vector_without_zeros);
bIdx = BBBB(Results_vector_without_zeros);
```

DISADVANTAGE : TOO MUCH RAM CONSUMPTION FOR LARGER MATRICES